# Determine if two strings are similar in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, logic

Let's say I have two strings, is there any way to check if they are at least 90% similar?

```
var string1 = "theBoardmeetstoday,tomorrow51";
var string2 = "Board meets today, tomorrow";
```

Thanks,

Tegan

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The wikipedia entry for [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) includes a sample implementation.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the exact revision of the page with this example (in case the example is deleted from the page?)

Comment: Here is the specific revision of the page (from October 14, 2010): http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Levenshtein_distance&oldid=384505495

Answer (score 12):

[jsdifflib](https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib) is a JavaScript port of Python's excellent [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) library.

It has a function `ratio()` which *"return[s] a measure of the sequences’ similarity as a float in the range [0, 1].*"

Answer (score 5):

Also consider [Dice's Coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient) which is considered "mostly better" than the Levenshtein distance by the creator of the [string-similarity](https://github.com/aceakash/string-similarity#readme) github repo and its corresponding [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-similarity).

Usage from its docs:

```
var stringSimilarity = require('string-similarity');

var similarity = stringSimilarity.compareTwoStrings('healed', 'sealed'); 

var matches = stringSimilarity.findBestMatch('healed', ['edward', 'sealed', 'theatre']);
```

Answer (score 4):

String.levenshtein (a plugin MooTools)

check it out: http://mootools.net/forge/p/string_levenshtein

GitHub: https://github.com/thinkphp/String.levenshtein

This method calculates Levenshtein distance between two strings. In information theory and computer science, the Levenshtein distance is a metric for measuring the amount of difference between two sequences (called edit distance). The Levenshtein distance between two strings is given by minimum number of operations needed to transform one string into another given string, where possible operations are insertion, deletion, or substitution of a single character.

The Levenshtein distance algorithm has been used in:

- Spell checking
- Speech recognition
- DNA analysis
- plagiarism detection

Comment: here is the same code but without mootools dependency - https://gist.github.com/luchaninov/a5730c453129ae159dfc

Answer (score 0):

piggybacking on other people's answers, I wrote a simple js function `stringsAreSimilar` to do this:

```js
// https://github.com/thinkphp/String.levenshtein/blob/master/Source/String.levenshtein.js

function getStringDifference(stringA, stringB) {
  var cost = [],
    str1 = stringA,
    str2 = stringB,
    n = str1.length,
    m = str2.length,
    i, j;

  var minimum = function (a, b, c) {
    var min = a;
    if (b < min) {
      min = b;
    }
    if (c < min) {
      min = c;
    }
    return min;
  };

  if (n == 0) {
    return;
  }
  if (m == 0) {
    return;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    cost[i] = [];
  }

  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    cost[i][0] = i;
  }

  for (j = 0; j <= m; j++) {
    cost[0][j] = j;
  }

  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {

    var x = str1.charAt(i - 1);

    for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) {

      var y = str2.charAt(j - 1);

      if (x == y) {

        cost[i][j] = cost[i - 1][j - 1];

      } else {

        cost[i][j] = 1 + minimum(cost[i - 1][j - 1], cost[i][j - 1], cost[i - 1][j]);
      }

    } //endfor

  } //endfor

  return cost[n][m];
}

function stringsAreSimilar(stringA, stringB) {
  var difference = getStringDifference(stringA, stringB);
  debugConsoleLog("stringA" + stringA);
  debugConsoleLog("stringB" + stringB);
  debugConsoleLog("difference" + difference);
  
  return difference < 10;
}

var string1 = "theBoardmeetstoday,tomorrow51";
var string2 = "Board meets today, tomorrow";

if(similar) {
    console.log("they are similar");
} else {
    console.log("they are not similar");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was trying to do this last year.  I read that `Levenshtein distance`  is the solution for this purpose the OP asked here.

I saw a code from a thread and was not given much upvotes.  Maybe because of its time complexity (having a forloop inside a forloop). I tried and it seem to work for me.  The function returns a score wherein 0 is a great match on the other hand a higher score means deviating from a close match.  Ill share and maybe someone can extend it or explain it better:

```js
function editDistance(s1, s2) {
    s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
    s2 = s2.toLowerCase();

    var costs = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i <= s1.length; i++) {
        var lastValue = i;
        for (var j = 0; j <= s2.length; j++) {
            if (i == 0) costs[j] = j;
            else {
                if (j > 0) {
                    var newValue = costs[j - 1];
                    if (s1.charAt(i - 1) != s2.charAt(j - 1))
                        newValue =
                            Math.min(Math.min(newValue, lastValue), costs[j]) +
                            1;
                    costs[j - 1] = lastValue;
                    lastValue = newValue;
                }
            }
        }
        if (i > 0) costs[s2.length] = lastValue;
    }
    return costs[s2.length];
}
```

Good luck and share your thoughts on this - would be awesome! Cheers!